# What is the best pratice to throw an exception from a modal dialog?

Tags: c++, exception, atl

I have a function that showing a model dialog and wait for the user to do something, however, it is complex and may have got something wrong and an exception would be thrown in this case.

Here is the supposed code that calling this function with exception handling:

```
try {
    CMyDialog mydialog();
    mydialog.DoModal();
}
catch(std::logic_error &e){
    DoExceptionHandling();
}
```

The dialog UI is written in ATL, and let us suppose there is a button OnClick handler as following:

```
LRESULT CMyDialog::OnBnClickedBlah(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD /*wID*/, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/){
    ...
    throw std::logic_error("BlahBlah");
}
```

When running the above code, however, once the exception has been thrown, in debug mode I triggered an ATL assertion that claims the HWND of the dialog should be null (but it is actually not cleared yet).

What I want to know is how to fix this problem and allow the exception to be captured by the caller, and makes sure all resource has bee freed properly?

Answer (score 1):

Some advice:

I would try not to throw exceptions across message boundaries, and especially not different modal message loops. There are several intervening layers, and even if it works (which it seems like it doesn't in this case), it's asking for trouble.

I'd suggest that you use EndDialog on an error, and store some sort of error code in the dialog class itself that the caller can examine on an "unexpected" result code from the dialog (eg: IDCANCEL). That way the dialog still "goes away" on error, everything is allowed to clean up properly, and you don't have to worry about making sure everything works with non-standard dialog error handling. My 2c.

Comment: Your advice is good. However I want to explain my motive here. The call to `DoModal` looks syntactically like a normal, GUI-less function call, because it blocks the execution flow until it has been finished. I understand that the implementations are actually quite different, but why it cannot be made the same? One solution for me is to encapsulate the dialog object creation and `DoModal` method into a single function and apply your advice .

Answer (score 1):

Calling `EndDialog` should fix your problem:

```
CMyDialog mydialog();
try {
    mydialog.DoModal();
}
catch(std::logic_error &e){
    mydialog.EndDialog(IDABORT);
    DoExceptionHandling();
}
```

And yes, passing exception across module boundaries is not recommended.